# Root file system mounts readonly most of the time - systemd

Tags: boot, mount

Over the past few days I upgraded a couple of my systems from LTS 12.04 to 16.04.3 via /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade (first to 14.04 then to 16.04).  They had been fine for *years*.  One of them seems to be fine after the upgrade.  The other, during most boots, ends up with a readonly root file system.  But once in a while it mounts just fine.

I have run fsck - the file system is fine.  Again, I repeat, the file system itself is FINE.

dmesg shows these message releated to the root file system (sda3) and "mount"

```
[    8.438116] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    8.451426] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   14.143079] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on systemd-remount-fs.service/start
[   14.143093] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job systemd-remount-fs.service/start  <<<<<<<< APPARENTLY A PROBLEM <<<<<<<<<<
[   14.143096] systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Job systemd-remount-fs.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
[   14.144423] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   37.065426] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   37.140357] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

/var/log/syslog shows:

```
Jan 13 14:06:39 linux4 kernel: [  554.047976] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 kernel: [    8.464055] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 kernel: [    8.477996] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 kernel: [   21.336148] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 kernel: [   36.133568] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 kernel: [   36.208451] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Jan 13 14:09:01 linux4 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jan 13 14:09:09 linux4 kernel: [   52.903086] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [    8.467847] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [    8.481156] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [   27.422276] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [   42.464741] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [   42.527596] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 kernel: [   44.178553] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Jan 13 14:14:28 linux4 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
```

The mount command shows:

```
root@linux4:/var/log# mount | grep sda
/dev/sda3 on / type ext3 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

/etc/fstab looks like this:

(The comments on /dev/scd0, /dev/scd1, /dev/fd0 were an attempt to eliminate them as suspects.  And, the first reboot after I made this change, the system came up correctly.  The comment /dev/sde1 is in error.  Swap is actually /dev/sda2.  And, / is /dev/sda3 and /boot is sda1.  Those comments date back from when Linux was on a second disk in a machine).

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# /dev/sdb3
UUID=f5e2f8ee-adac-48ad-8483-e04ae0da9580 /               ext3    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /dev/sdb1
#UUID=2f2eef15-17d3-4886-9ffa-6666dc8ad8d4 /boot           ext3    relatime        0       2
# /dev/sde2
UUID=d6054f01-2d94-4b27-8662-3ba22ab123c9 none            swap    sw              0       0
# /dev/scd1       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
# /dev/scd0       /media/cdrom1   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
# /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
UUID=2f2eef15-17d3-4886-9ffa-6666dc8ad8d4       /boot   ext3    defaults        0       2
```

Kernel is:

```
root@linux4:/var/log# uname -a
Linux linux4 4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:07 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Curiously, the other system that I upgraded is running kernel is 3.13.0-139-generic, rather than 4.4.0-109-generic - even though I took them both thru the same update processes only days apart.  I also tried kernel 4.4.0.104-generic, which the same results.  The previous kernel I had been running was 3.2.0-69-generic-pae on this system.

I am at a loss.  This "systemd" thing is completely new to me, though I have been working with Unix since 1976 (no, that is not a typo).  So, yes, I will be researching it, but I am hoping someone out there might be able to give me some pointers where I might begin to look.

I looked at the topic "root file system mounts as read only after some time", and it did not have an answer, and that topic was two years old.

It is very hard not to start a rant about systemd being "wonderful" - a term we used where I worked for many years to describe something that was unnecessarily complex and arcane (and often unnecessary at all).

Comment: So, after doing some digging, I found that after it messes up, by mounting / as ro, if I then start systemd-remount-fs.service, it does indeed mount rw.  So, this is clearly a BUG (dependency loop or timing) somwehere in the systemd setup.  I see that there have been some updates since I did the install.  I will try installing those and report back.